# How can I deprecate a class on hacklang?

Tags: hacklang

I have an old class and I want to deprecate it.
I added a deprecation as Phpdoc:

```
/**
*  @deprecated use MyNewClass.
*/
class MyDeprecatedClass {
 
   public static function doDeprecatedThings() {...}
   ...
}
```

Which is pretty soft.  I like to have a more explicit error or notation for future devs, and there is a deprecation warning describe on:
https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/attributes/predefined-attributes#__deprecated

Sadly seems to work for functions/methods.

My current approach is to go to all public methods and flag them as deprecated, which isn't ideal. Also is use statically, so deprecating the constructor is not a full fix.

Is there a way to deprecate the whole class?

Comment: Deprecating the constructor may work if the class is mostly for instances rather than static methods. Attempts to construct lead to "The method __construct is deprecated: ...".

Comment: Actually is a good idea, but I didn't mentioned, my class is use statically. I'll update the example.

Comment: While I agree a standard way to deprecate a class would be useful, I'd like to understand why marking every function in a class as deprecated is hard. sounds like a straightforward find/replace to me.